# How to prevent attacker from running PHP code embedded in a jpg image by knowing the URL of that image?

Tags: php

*How to run php code embedded in a jpg image by knowing the URL of that image ?*

imagine a hacker has uploaded a contaminated jpg with php code to server
Now he wants to execute his php code and he knows the URL of the image too

I know if the image is executed with the php files of the server , php code of the hacker will be executed too

for example the below code of the server will execute the hacker's php code in the image:

```
<h1>Problem?</h1>
<img src="img1.jpg">
<?php
include "./img1.jpg";
```

but if I take care of the included files and prevent execution of unknown included files, naturally the hacker's php code will not be executed 
(for example with defining a constant in the included files which are supposed to be included and checking that constant in the file which is supposed to include those files)

the question is:
***Is there another solution for the hacker to execute his php code in the image when he knows the URL of the image too or not ?***

FYI: the images are uploaded with an android app to the server

Thanks in advance

**Edit:**
This is the structure of the server:

**public-html:**
It contains B.PHP file which just includes A.PHP file from home folder (non public)
It contains user uploaded images too

**Home Folder which is non public:**
It contains A.PHP file which will be included by B.PHP file in public-html
It contains some other data too,for example name and phone number of the users

A.PHP is responsible for uploading files to public-html and to home folder too
For example:
Some json data will be uploaded in home folder and some images will be uploaded in public-html area
Is this structure dangerous ?

Comment: If people can upload arbitrary files to the same server that has your PHP code you're already playing with fire. If they can inject PHP code it doesn't matter if they can upload files, it's already game over. My advice: **Never** allow uploads to your production server. Always use an object store on a separate server or service like Amazon S3. You have no way of knowing if an image is actually an image and doesn't contain a hostile payload. Image verification tools can be fooled.

Comment: Even if the php files of the server are not in the public-html folder?

Comment: The risk is that changing one tiny configuration directive could make your user upload directory suddenly start executing `.php` files just as the opposite can happen and your `.php` scripts show up as raw source, potentially revealing all sorts of things you don't want to get out. Generally uploads go into some sort of public area so they can be served up as static assets. That's where you're exposed. If you can avoid that by off-loading this to a special-purpose asset store you can reduce the risk dramatically.

Comment: In my Android App, users shall upload images, the server shall have a php file to be connected with the Android App to upload the images, so I shall have both php and user upload folders in the same server,true?

Comment: Ideally separate servers. If that's not practical then separate virtual hosts on the same server, each with their own specific configuration.

Comment: Thanks for the comments

Answer (score 0):

A proper setup of your NGINX or Apache will prevent this kind of thing when someone accesses the image by the URL. All files on server have particular type, and it distinguishes which ones will be run, and which ones will be returned to the user. That's what file handlers are configured for in the Apache configuration so that it knows that it ONLY has to run files with php/php5/php7 extensions.

Reading contents from the file somewhere on the server is no different than from a local directory. Doing include on it WILL NOT RUN the file ON THE SERVER, for the exception if the coder doing the inclusion is also on that same server. In this case attacker already managed to create a PHP file on the server, and it doesn't make difference where the rest of the code is stored - locally or remotely in some obscure file.

The other case is when attacker manages to replace a file in the known directory on the server, yet again if it's not with php extension it won't be run since proper developers will not be storing PHP code in a file with JPG extension.

Comment: Thanks for the answer